# Android delivering different Cell IDs (Neighboring Cell Info)

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager, cellid

Using an Android Dev Phone 2, I'm using the GsmCellLocation.getCid() method to get the Cell ID on my network. When I run the command and get all the CellIDs for 
the NeighboringCellInfo I get this values:

597195726 
 
597185722 
597195718 
597110191 
597101100 
597175726

I'm running this using the SDK 1.6.

The problem is that when I run the Engineering Mode on a GSM modem 
that I have, running a command to obtain the Neighboring Cell IDs, I 
get this values: 
34253 
0 
34223 
34262 
34181 
0

What is the difference here? In what format is Android delivering the 
Cell IDs?

I tried doing a "cell.getCid() & 0xffff" but now I'm getting the 
values: 
21690 
31686 
37068 
11695 
11694 
31694

Which are still different from the one that the GSM Modem is 
delivering with the Engineering Mode.

Obviously I tried this on at the same time, same location.

I'm trying to get the same Cell IDs that the external GSM modem I using is delivering.

Comment: Where you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I didn't continue working with that project anymore, sorry

Answer (score 1):

It could be that Android is reporting cell id's for 3G, and your GSM modem is not.  I have been looking into this a bit myself and have found that when I turn off 3G on my android phone, the cell ID's are generally 5 digit numbers.  When I turn 3G on, I get longer cell Id's. Just a thought.

Comment: I tried turning off 3G on my phone (Enabling the "use 2G only" option) and I still get the same Cell IDs, weird!